# How to add a css in vue-bootstrap table template

Tags: css, vue.js, html-table

I want to add a CSS to bootstrap vue table template but it doesn't work

```
<template slot="actions" slot-scope="data" :style="{min-width:'150px'}">
    <b-button variant="info" @click="showViewModel(data.item)">
       <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
    </b-button>
   <b-button variant="danger" class="ml-1" @click="showConfirmBox(data.item.id,data.index)">
       <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
   </b-button>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <template slot="actions" slot-scope="data">
    <div :style="'min-width:150px'">
      <b-button variant="info" @click="showViewModel(data.item)">
         <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
      </b-button>
      <b-button variant="danger" class="ml-1" @click="showConfirmBox(data.item.id,data.index)">
       <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
      </b-button>
    </div>
  </template>
```

Comment: Any reason you're binding your style instead of just `style="min-width: 150px"` ?

Answer (score 0):

Vue's `template` tag renders into nothing, so adding style to it has no effect.

Also, adding style with Vue you should use plain strings instead of objects. So instead of this:

```
:style="{min-width:'150px'}"
```

Use this:

```
:style="'min-width:150px'"
```

Comment: @S.Gandhi it'll never work with `<template>`, it doesn't render into anything. Replace it with a real tag like `<div>`

Comment: its is necessary for custom data rendering so I can not remove it

Comment: @S.Gandhi then add a div immediately inside the template and move the style to it